# Searching with Smart Search shows HTML-Code of articles

Tags: joomla-2.5, smartsearch

I use the Smart Search of Joomla 2.5. So I added it and made an Index etc.

It works but it also shows some HTML-Code of the articles within results. I don't want that a User can see that.

How can I avoid this?

Here a Screenshot as an example:

[image: Smart Search shows HTML-Code within result]

Comment: This should not happen. Does that "partial" HTML show also on other views of your site or just in this one? If you're using a template other than Joomla's default, maybe it's an issue related with your template's override for com_finder results view. You can check it by switching default template for a moment and reloading results page to see if the issue remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your articles contains additional HTML code that has a `"`, `>` or `<` in the wrong place. If you copied your content from Word (or another text editor), or made changes to your html code, you'd get results like this. The `mso-` prefixes strongly suggest this code comes from some Microsoft Office application, which I would guess means Word.

Here's an example. If your HTML code looks like this:

```
...it is ensured that<span>style="font-size:9.0pt;font-familiy:Symbol:mso-fareast-font:Symbol;mso-bidi-font-family:Symbol"> the parts can indeed...
```

It would produce a result similar to your second example.

I recommend you open the articles in question, and if you're using the default TinyMCE editor, look for the <kbd>< ></kbd> button in the toolbar, or press <kbd>Toggle Editor</kbd> below the text window. This will display your HTML code.

It's a common problem that this kind of [inline styling](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/inline.php) is added when copying from Word, thus overriding your template's CSS styles. You can paste as pure text using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, or paste to Notepad first and then copy-paste to Joomla.